# Global variable scoped to each request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, global-variables, rack

Is it possible to have a global variable in Rails that is scoped to each request? Meaning, the variable doesn't persist across Rack requests.

I need this because I want to be able to raise events throughout the application. At the end of the request, I want to be able to collect these raised events in an array and send them to the client.

Comment: What exact problem are you trying to solve here? Why are you raising events and not using something like `ActiveSupport::Notifications`?

Comment: I want to send an array of events to the front-end along with the json response. More specifically, I want trigger events that may require a UI update.

Comment: maybe a websocket approach would be better suited?